# Valid code and compiler errors in MPLAB X

Tags: c, c99, xc8

I have main file:

```
#include "modbus.h"

void main(void)
{
    modbus_frame_t frame;
    // (...)   

    // ERROR ON LINE BELOW
    // main.c:59:: error: (712) can't generate code for this expression
    crc16(frame, 1); 
}
```

This is "modbus.h" file:

```
#ifndef MODBUS_H
#define MODBUS_H

#define MODBUS_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE 74

struct modbus_frame {
    unsigned char * data[MODBUS_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char * len; 
};

typedef struct modbus_frame modbus_frame_t;

char crc16(modbus_frame_t f, char check);

#endif
```

And this is "modbus.c" file:

```
#include "modbus.h"

char crc16(modbus_frame_t f, char check) {
    // (...)
}
```

MPLAB XC8 2.05 compiler says:

main.c:59:: error: (712) can't generate code for this expression

When I change struct to:

```
struct modbus_frame {
    unsigned char data[MODBUS_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char len; 
};
```

it throws diffrent error which doesn't make sense (undefined symbol _crc16()).

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I remember a compiler problem in XC8 like that, about *[] array. So, I don't think it's a code error.

Comment: The code is valid C. The error is because this compiler is stupid. *"This error indicates that a C expression is too difficult for the code generator to actually 
compile. For successful code generation, the code generator must know how to compile an expression and there must be enough resources (i.e., registers or temporary 
memory locations) available. Simplifying the expression, i.e., using a temporary variable to hold an intermediate result, may work around this message."* - from it's docs

Comment: I would say you are out of memory. Try smaller `frame` just to see if it removes this error.

Comment: And by the way, I think you want `unsigned char  data[MODBUS_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE];` rather than `unsigned char * data[MODBUS_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE];` The `len` field type is also questionable

Comment: @EugeneSh. I changed `unsigned char *` to `unsigned char` types in struct. Now compiler says ":0:: error: (499) undefined symbol:
 _crc16(dist/default/...production.o) "

Comment: @EugeneSh. This microcontroller has 8k RAM, and my buffer size is below 100.

Comment: RAM is used for different things.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I removed array from my struct and I have same result.

Comment: Please post [mcve] then. Maybe the issue is not where you believe it is.

Comment: Also, try passing the struct as a pointer. Maybe it can't pass the whole struct via stack or whatever it is using.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I found it. Thank you for "The code is valid C" and "The error is because this compiler is stupid" hints. It was not stupid compiler, but stupid me and stupid MPLAB IDE :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

Files "modbus.h" and "modbus.c" were added in "Files" tool-window, like this:

[image]

but they were missing in project structure:

[image]

and MPLAB did not consider these files in **make** command parameters.

I didn't expected that.

After I added "modbus.h" and "modbus.c" (add existing file) in project structure - eventhing works as expected.